# PrestaShop as a 3-tier architecture

Tags: php, model-view-controller, prestashop

If PrestaShop is based on a 3-tier architecture (MVC), what is the name of the controller that renders the .tpl files inside a theme?

e.g myProject/themes/default("Default theme in Prestashop")/(.tpl files)

or maybe where I can find the location of the controller that renders the .tpl files? So that I can add more smarty tags?

```
//Assume this file is the controller that renders the .tpl files in a theme

//I got this code for converting a php value to a smarty tag in creating a module http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'Hello' => "Hello",
    'World' => "World",
    'another_smarty_tag' => "Im another smarty tag"
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming, you use PS 1.5

Basically, you put your variables into an array, like you posted, or just create another statement `$this->context->smarty->assign()` and put stuff there, PrestaShop will take care of it. and push it to the templates.

Get yourself comfortable with [`overriding controllers`](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors).

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'Hello' => "Hello",
    'World' => "World",
    'another_smarty_tag' => "Im another smarty tag",
    'I am another variable' => 'And I have a value :o'
    …
));
```

> or maybe where I can find the location of the controller that renders the .tpl files? So that I can add more smarty tags?

In essence, every controller does that. Particularly loading of the template fiels is going on in a method `initContent()` and template files are set through `$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'order-follow.tpl');`